# Python filter list with recent date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of products with their name and time. I want to create a list that retrieved the most recent date for the kind of product. My initial plan is to create a sublist for each kind of product and the get the most recent of that sublist. I want to know if there is more efficient way of doing it since there could be more on the list.

```
products = [{'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'},
            {'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'},
            {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'},
            {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}]


Veggies = [x for x in products if x['name'] == 'Veggie']
...
new_products.append(get_recent(Veggies))
```

Desired output:

```
new_products = [{'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'},
            {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could iterate through the dictionary and make a set of product types, then iterate through that to make the sublists and get_recent. It doesn't speed anything up, but at least you're not manually creating sublists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option using `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

products = [
    {'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'},
    {'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'},
    {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'},
    {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}
]

d = defaultdict(list)

for product in products:
    d[product['name']].append(product['time'])

new_products = [{'name': item, 'time': max(times)} for item, times in d.items()]
```

And the result will be:

```py
pprint(new_products)
[{'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'},
 {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}]
```

Comment: May I just throw it in that it does not catch the original object. Rather creating a new list with with the recent time.

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: Certainly there are other solutions and probable one that preserves the original objects, but I don't see a good reason for that. I try to go the most simple way as possible.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can order a list of dictionary by any key you want.
In this example, products(or Veggies )  is passed to the built-in ​sorted() function, which accepts a keyword argument key. Itemgetter creates a callable that accepts a single item from the product(or Veggies) array and as input and returns a value that will be used as the basis for sorting it.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

products = [{'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'},
            {'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'},
            {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'},
            {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}]

rows_by_date = sorted(products, key=itemgetter('time'))
print(rows_by_date)
```

OUTPUT

```
[{'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'}, 
{'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'}, 
{'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}, 
{'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}]
```

Comment: Hmmm so it sorts them by date. It lacks removing the unwanted objects. Thanks for the insight though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to sort your data first then you can do reduce to eliminate duplicate record

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import itemgetter

products = [{'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'},
            {'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'},
            {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-01-06T07:53:29Z'},
            {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}]

def validate_unique_product(a, b):
    if b['name'] in map(lambda x: x['name'], a):
        return a
    a.append(b)
    return a


sorted_products = sorted(products, key=itemgetter('time'), reverse=True)
unique_products = reduce(validate_unique_product, sorted_products, [])

print(unique_products)
```

### output

```
>> [{'name': 'Veggie', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}, {'name': 'Fruit', 'time': '2020-02-02T07:12:13Z'}]
```